# XML Include elements from another xml

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

So we have a xml file :

EnglandCities.xml

```
<Cities>
    <City Name="London">
        other children
    </City>
    <City Name="Southampton">
        other children
    </City>
</Cities>
```

Now we need a second file say :
UKCities.xml

```
<Cities>
    <City Name="London">
        other children
    </City>
    <City Name="Southampton">
        other children
    </City>
    <City Name="Belfast">
        other children
    </City>
    <City Name="Edinburgh">
        other children
    </City>
</Cities>
```

This UKCities.xml has new  entries "Belfast" & "Edinburgh".

Can we do a xml:include (or something similar) in UKCities.xml to get "London" & "Southampton" elements from EnglandCities.xml instead of typing them in?
Something of the sorts as below:

```
<Cities>
    <xml:include file="EnglandCities.xml"/>
    <City Name="Belfast">
        other children
    </City>
    <City Name="Edinburgh">
        other children
    </City>
</Cities>
```

Comment: If UKCities.xml is the file you want to create, then where do "Belfast" and "Edinburgh" come from?

Comment: We know of the values and they will be present in UKCities.xml. Trouble is about including rest of the EnglandCities.xml.
It is more like a XML Merge issue!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please state clearly what is the input (if there are multiple input XML files, that's okay - just be clear about it) and what is the required output. Right now it seems you are asking how to get something from nothing.

Comment: Apologies for that. I just edited it. Please let me know if it still seems vague.

Comment: "*Please let me know if it still seems vague.*" Letting you know.

Comment: One final attempt at explaining. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged this as "xslt" which suggests you may be interested in an XSLT solution. (If this is not the case, please remove the tag, and I will delete this answer).

But assuming you can use XSLT, you could make use of the **document()** function to reference the "EnglandCities.xml" within the XSLT

```
<xsl:copy-of select="document('EnglandCities.xml')/*/*" />
```

Or maybe (if you were using the [Identity Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)....)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('EnglandCities.xml')/*/*" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="include" select="'EnglandCities.xml'" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="document($include)/*/*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your original XML, the following is output

```
<Cities>
  <City Name="London">
        other children
    </City>
  <City Name="Southampton">
        other children
    </City>
    <City Name="Belfast">
        other children
    </City>
    <City Name="Edinburgh">
        other children
    </City>
</Cities>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to find a xml only way. But I can use your technique as I have a util which can apply the xslt (does seem like a hack).